# Buttons same size in a horizontal menu bar?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a horizontal nav menu using css, but I'm having problems getting the buttons the same size, since they all adjust to the text length. I've tried several tips: fixed width, padding, text-align, using em instead of px. Some of them seems to work if I use display:block for a vertical menu, but as soon as I change to display:inline it doesn't work anymore.

Here's my code for the navigation bar:

```
#navigation li {
display: inline; 
padding: 20px;
text-decoration: none; 
font-size: 2em; 
background-image: url(../pics/skylt.png); 
background-size: 175px 60px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: 0px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline` elements adjust to the size of their contents.

You could try using `inline-block` combined with a `width` (ok) or `min-width` (better) to get them to the same size.

Or, if you want to go a slightly more complicated route, you could use `display:table-cell` with a few details to enforce that they're always equal sizes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it looks just fine! :)

Comment: If this helped, perhaps you wouldn't mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Too new here... :)